# java class :" classname referenced to newMethodName "

Tags: java

```
public class foo{
  private String label;

   foo(String whereto){
   label = whereto;
      }

 public foo bar(String name){
 return new foo(name);    
    }
 }
```

can any one explain , why they have used class name as reference to method name & what's it purpose using it ?

Comment: You will get a `compilation error` unless you return an instance of type `foo`

Comment: when you specify a return type make sure to return specified type object otherwise return null. Unless you will get compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type `foo` is used to return a new object of type `foo` out of a given object of type `foo`. A prominent example is `BigDecimal` representing an immutable value object and where the `add` operation returns a newly constructed `BigDecimal` representing the old value plus the new value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class foo{ // class foo
   public foo bar(String name){ // method bar
    System.out.print(name)  // you need to return instance of foo
    return new foo(name);       
 } 
}
```

When you call the method `bar` that will return an instance of `foo`. That's why return type of `bar` is `foo`.

Further, use better `Java` naming while coding

```
  public class Foo{ // uppercase start for class name
   public foo bar(String name){ // lowercase start for method name
       System.out.print(name)      
       return new FOO(name);   
   } 
  }
```

For your edit:

```
  foo(String whereto){ // this is a constructor for foo class
     label = whereto;
  }
```

It means if you want to create an instance of `foo`. you should do as follows

```
 foo f=new foo("a"); // constructor of foo accepting String;
```

Comment: ya thanks for naming convention in java . but what is use of creating a method with return type of class name as follows //public foo bar();

Comment: @P_O_I_S_O_N you have the answer in the beginning. It is just a method which will return instance of `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

They haven't used class name as reference. Return type of `bar` method is of type `foo.class`.
That means `bar()` method is returning object(or say reference to an object of type `foo`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey bro, if you are new to java then I will suggest you to read "Head First Java". It's nice book that will clear your all doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Class name is not exactly a reference here. It is the return type of method, as they call it in java. Also, your method will throw a compilation error because it does not return a foo as 
stated in the signature. It can be corrected as follows.

```
public class foo{
 public foo bar(String name){
 System.out.print(name);
 return new foo();
     }
 }
```